# Reply twice from outlook add in itemadd event

Tags: office-interop, outlook-addin

I need to reply twice from an Outlook Add-in item_Add event, once as soon as the mail arrives and once more after some processing. The code for the registered callback looks somewhat as below:

```
void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
  Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
  Outlook.MailItem reply = mail.Reply();
  // Add some stuff to reply body and subject
  reply.Send();
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(reply); 
  // Some processing for few seconds
  reply = mail.Reply();
  // Update reply body and subject
  reply.Send()
  // Release reply object
}
```

The problem I have is the 2 replies are sent out at the end after processing is complete. Is there a way to send the first reply immediately and not wait till the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, you run the code from the event handler. The handler should return the control flow to Outlook to process your replies.

You can try to use [SyncObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860705(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Namespace class to force the synchronization.

```
Public Sub Sync() 
  Dim nsp As Outlook.NameSpace  
  Dim sycs As Outlook.SyncObjects  
  Dim syc As Outlook.SyncObject  
  Dim i As Integer  
  Dim strPrompt As Integer  
  Set nsp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
  Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects  
  For i = 1 To sycs.Count  
    Set syc = sycs.Item(i)  
    strPrompt = MsgBox("Do you wish to synchronize " & syc.Name &"?", vbYesNo)  
    If strPrompt = vbYes Then  
     syc.Start   
    End If  
  Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The details you gave helped. I had to modify the approach a bit, I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had modify the code as below:

```
...
outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
...
void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
{
  Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
  Outlook.MailItem reply = mail.Reply();
  // Add some stuff to reply body and subject
  reply.Send();
  outlookNameSpace.Session.SendAndReceive(false);
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(reply); 
  // Some processing for few seconds
  reply = mail.Reply();
  // Update reply body and subject
  reply.Send()
  // Release reply object
}
```

Thanks